# Value of -1 in return statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to know that how it print the line when value of return is -1. Also, I don't know about what does the -1 do, like 1 for true and 0 for false, but what is for -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {
    int day, month, year;
};

int compare_dates(struct date d1, struct date d2) {
    if(d1.year < d2.year)
        return -1;
    else if(d1.year > d2.year)
        return 1;
    else if(d1.month < d2.month) 
            return -1;
    else if(d1.month > d2.month) 
            return 1;
    else if(d1.day < d2.day) 
            return -1;
    else if(d1.day > d2.day)
            return 1;
    else
        return 0;


}

int main(void) {
    struct date d1, d2;
    printf("Enter first date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &d1.day, &d1.month, &d1.year);
    printf("Enter second date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &d2.day, &d2.month, &d2.year);

    if(compare_dates(d1, d2)) 
        printf("Date1 comes after than Date2");
    else if(!compare_dates(d1, d2))
        printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal");
    else if(-1)
        printf("Date1 comes before than Date2");

}
```

Comment: `-1` can mean whatever you want it to.

Comment: The result of `compare_dates()` isn't a condition, it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a function called `dates_are_equal`, returning 0 or 1 (or more generally 0 or non-0), it would make sense to use the result directly as a condition:

```
if (dates_are_equal(d1, d2)) {
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal\n");
}
else {
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are not equal\n");
}
```

But your `compare_dates` function can return any of three different integer values, with three distinct meanings. The result is a number, not a condition, so don't treat it as a condition.  Instead, build a condition by comparing the result to another integer.

There are several ways you can do this.  By analogy with `strcmp()`, which indicates the result of the comparison by returning a value less than, equal to, or greater than `0` (not necessarily just `-1`, `0`, or `-1`), you can write:

```
int comparison = compare_dates(d1, d2);
if (comparison < 0) {
    printf("Date1 comes before Date2\n");
}
else if(comparison == 0) {
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal\n");
}
else { // No need to test again here
    printf("Date1 comes after Date2\n");
}
```

If you want to assume that `compare_dates()` can only return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, you can use a switch statement:

```
switch (compare_dates(d1, d2)) {
    case -1:
        printf("Date1 comes before Date2\n");
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Date1 comes after Date2\n");
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Internal error, unexpected result\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I *don't* recommend using `(!comparison)` in place of `(comparison == 0)`. It's perfectly legal, and it means exactly the same thing to the compiler, but in my opinion it's better to reserve the `!` operator for values that really are logically boolean.

It's common practice to use treat non-boolean expressions as conditions, such as writing

```
if (!strcmp(s1, s2)) {
    /* the strings pointed to by s1 and s2 are equal */
}
```

or

```
if (!ptr) {
    /* ptr is a null pointer */
}
```

but I find that being more explicit makes the code easier to read:

```
if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) {
    /* the strings pointed to by s1 and s2 are equal */
}
```

or

```
if (ptr != NULL) {
    /* ptr is a null pointer */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your compare_dates function it appears that `1` will be returned if date d1 is `greater` than date d2, `-1` will be returned if date d1 will be `lesser` than date d2 and `0` will be returned if both dates are `same`.

So, your code should be like below:

```
   int main(void) 
   {
        struct date d1, d2;
        int result;
        printf("Enter first date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &d1.day, &d1.month, &d1.year);
        printf("Enter second date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &d2.day, &d2.month, &d2.year);

        result = compare_dates(d1, d2);
        if(1 == result)
            printf("Date1 comes after than Date2");
        else if(0 == result)
            printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal");
        else if(-1 == result)
            printf("Date1 comes before than Date2");

   }
```

Comment: `1 == result` is sometimes called a ["Yoda condition"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). It avoids accidentally writing `if (result = 1)` rather than `if (result == 1)`, but IMHO it's not worth the loss of readability, particularly since most compilers will warn about assignments used as conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if(compare_dates(d1, d2)) 
    printf("Date1 comes after than Date2");
else if(!compare_dates(d1, d2))
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal");
else if(-1)
    printf("Date1 comes before than Date2");
```

Is messed up.  You should call compare_dates a single time and compare its result against the various possibilities.

In particular, `if(-1)` is nonsense, since it will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

In C, 0 is False, everything else is True.

In your code you would have to do

```
if(compare_dates(d1, d2) == 1) 
    printf("Date1 comes after than Date2");
else if(!compare_dates(d1, d2))
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal");
else if(compare_dates(d1, d2) == -1)
    printf("Date1 comes before than Date2");
```

or, more efficient

```
int value = compare_dates(d1, d2)
if(value == 1) 
    printf("Date1 comes after than Date2");
else if(!value)
    printf("Date1 and Date2 are equal");
else if(value == -1)
    printf("Date1 comes before than Date2");
```

For compare functions, 0 usualy means the values are equal, -1 means the first argument is smaller than the second, and 1 means that the first argument is larger than the second

Comment: Using `!value` rather than `value == 0` is IMHO confusing. `value` isn't a boolean.

Comment: It isn't that confusing. It actually is a common practice, eg: if(!strcmp(str1, str2)){}

Comment: I know it's common practice. That doesn't make it a good idea. I find `if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0) {...}` easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In C everything that is `!= 0` is true.

```
if(-1) // = true
if(0)  // = false
if(1)  // = true
if(1234567) // = true
```

To print a message depending on the return value, use `switch`:

```
switch(compare_dates(d1, d2)){
    case -1: {
        // do whatever should done when compare_dates returns -1
        break; //don't forget the break
    }
    case 0: {
        // do whatever should done when it returns 0
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 0 signifies that d1 and d2 are equal. Allow me to explain:

-1 means d1 is less than d2. Hence the "less than" operator `<` corresponding to -1.
0 means d1 is equal to d2. Hence the "equal to" operator `==` corresponding.
1 means d1 is greater than d2. Hence the "greater than" operator `>` corresponding to 1.

This is just convention, probably influenced by the C standard `strcmp` function which uses the same convention.